# Matlab how to bitwise-AND of a vector and a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I want to find out the index of the matrix column in which the vector appears. My idea is to do AND of the vector over matrix and only the column that is the same will be 1 in the new vecotr. But I don't know how to do this. Below is example:

```
H =
0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1

S =
0   1   0   1
```

From that I want to get 2 as second column or even better vector

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 ... 0
```

Since there is error in second column.

How can I do this in Matlab or even better Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy with broadcasting. The following will require Octave 3.6.0 or later but you can use `bsxfun` if you have a previous version:

```
octave-cli-3.8.1> h = logical ([
0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1]);
octave-cli-3.8.1> s = logical ([0   1   0   1]');
octave-cli-3.8.1> all (h == s)
ans =

   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

From here, it's all a matter of using find to get the column numbers. It will even work if it matches more than 1 column:

```
octave-cli-3.8.1> find (all (h == s))
ans =  2
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure how you tried to approach the problem. But with `repmat` or `bsxfun` it is as simple as this:

```
all(bsxfun(@eq,H,S'))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
result = sum(H==repmat(S(:),[1 size(H,2)]))==4;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out the function

```
ismember(H', S, "rows")
```

works exactly as I want. Your answers are all good too, thanks.

Comment: yes, this will work as well but 1) you will need to transverse the large matrix, and even if that is not an issue, 2) it will be at last 10x slower which for large matrices will make make a difference. Just try with `H = rand (10, 1000000);` and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that comment I really don't have such knowledge in matlab to know that. I will change to your suggestion

Comment: ups, I meant "transpose", and not "transverse", on my first comment.

Comment: I used my solution to improve Octave's `ismember()` for the specific case of 1 row in `S`. This means that if you use Octave 4.2 or later (not yet released, `ismember` will actually be using be using broadcasting in the back. See cset [89055521e04d](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/89055521e04d)